# Hidden checkbox in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hello How can I make hidden multi checkbox in zend form?

Comment: What markup would you like to be generated? "Hidden multi checkbox" sounds ambigious. You either want hidden inputs, or checkboxes. Do you want the checkboxes to be *styled* as hidden, via CSS?

Comment: Yes I want to have multi checkbox in my form that not shown

Comment: actually I get the checkbox value from another form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Brandon_R:

In your form:

```
$hiddenBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('hidden', array(
    'class' => 'hideMe'
));
```

In your css:

```
input.hideMe{ display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This "could" work. Iam not on my dev machine in the moment

```
$box = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('checkbox');
// set view helper to render, to formHidden
$box->helper = 'formHidden';
```

Comment: I think this hide form ! not only checkbox

Comment: take a look on Zend_Form_Element_Hidden, this uses altough this helper

Answer (score 0):

Using the Zend_Form_Decorator, set the css class of the item in question to hidden and in the stylesheet create a style and set the display property to hidden.